# How do you replace a Kubernetes Master node on AWS?

Tags: kubernetes

How do I replace a downed master node?  In particular, how do you replace a node on AWS if you are using the kubernetes tools?

If I restart the node, it doesn't start correctly, if I clone the node, it definitely does not.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to connect the new master to the current etcd cluster, or create a new etcd cluster from a snapshot of the old one, in order to preserve state of the cluster.  Aside from that, you have to ensure that the nodes point to the new master's IP address.  I also suggest looking at HA masters if you are running a version greater than 1.0.X http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/high-availability.html.

Answer (score 0):

If replacing it comes up with a new IP, you'll have to update all your nodes, which know how to reach it by IP or by internal DNS (in flags).